# Como capturar datos Javascript con PHP sin uso de superglobales en AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, php7, http, cabeceras-http

Luego de revisar varios post no encuentro una solucion exacta a mi problema debido a que todos usan jquery y esa cosa es ilegible. Mi problema es que no se como implementar ajax del todo. Sigo tutoriales pero no entiendo esto de las cabeceras, protocolos y todo lo que esta en la teoria de http, lo cual siento que es muy importante saberlo para poderlo implementar.

Mi idea es que mande los datos con un objeto `XMLHttpRequest` y con el metodo `send(1300)` pueda capturar este numero como un codigo para que lo detecte el archivo PHP y asi sepa que devolver (notese en mi codigo que uso `'POST'` solo por el hecho de que no quiero que se muestre ninguna accion en la URL lo cual puede cambiar pero no se que mas existe para hacer las cosas de forma oculta) . Me cuesta implementar esto ya que no quiero usar variables globales como `$_POST` o `$_REQUEST` si existe alguna forma de recoger estos datos, haganmelo saber, pero si no existe otra forma y estoy obligado a usar las superglobales entonces puedo resignarme.

Estoy creando una web dinamica donde hago dos tipos de peticiones:

- Cuando se carga la pagina web debe cargarme un captcha generado
- Cuando se aprete el boton de `update-captcha` debe rehacerse otro captcha ( se puede enviar una request sin estos ser formulario? )
- Cuando aprete el boton `Buscar` con un `eventListener` envio los datos del formulario como JSON y hago la busqueda; si es satisfactioria, lanzo el archivo a descargar y comunico a la pagina web que muestre un `modalbox` verde con mensaje y con un `eventListener` de X que borre el modal. Y si no es satisfactorio, que de todas formas PHP lo comunique y haga que genere otro mensaje modal rojo, comunicando que no se encontro el archivo.

Mi implementacion usa en javascript:

```
...
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('searchBtn');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // si esta vacio no envies nada y termina la funcion
    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('input').length; i++)
        if (document.querySelectorAll('input')[i].value === '') return;
    // enviar datos
    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const formData = {
        'nombre' : document.getElementById('0fxa').value,
        'identidad' : document.getElementById('0fxb').value,
        'numero' : document.getElementById('0fxc').value,
        'captcha' : document.getElementById('captchaInput').value,
    }
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(formData);
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'download.php', true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpRequest.send(jsonStr);
});
...
{
    // este fragmento tambien esta en un event listener del boton update-captcha
    // peticion para envie el captcha y si es asi recoger la imagen
    let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById(element).src = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'download.php', true);
    // lanzar peticion 1040 para que identifique que se pide una imagen
    httpRequest.send(1040);
}
...
{
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // falta agregar el evento para que X -> &#x2716; destruya el modalbox
    httpRequest.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            if (this.responseText === 'success') {
                let modal = document.createElement('div');
                modal.className = 'message-success';
                modal.innerHTML = '<span>La descarga se ha iniciado</span><span>&#x2716;</span>';
                document.body.appendChild(modal);
            }
        } else {
            let modal = document.createElement('div');
            modal.className = 'message-error';
            modal.innerHTML = '<span>Archivo no encontrado</span><span>&#x2716;</span>'
            document.body.appendChild(modal);
        }
    }
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'download.php', true);
    // codigo 1020 para pedir confirmacion de que sucedio y generar la modalbox
    httpRequest.send(1020);
}
...
```

En mi codigo de PHP no quiero revelar todo el algoritmo pero si quiero saber como detectar estos codigos que envio y que segun eso al archivo `download.php` sepa como comportarse y dar una respuesta diferente segun el codigo:

```
<?php
include_once 'captcha.php';
$captcha = new Captcha();
// no se como capturar el codigo enviado con ajax sin superglobales
if (CODIGO_HTTP_ENVIADO == 1040) {
    // no se si echo es la manera adecuada de enviar la imagen
    echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($captcha->picture());
}
if (CODIGO_HTTP_ENVIADO == 1020) {
    $json_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $decoded_data = json_decode($json_data);

    if ($decoded_data->{'key'} == $captcha->key()) {
    //envia success para que sepa que modal crear
    echo 'success'
    // se efectua la descarga
    } else {
    ...
    // envia error para que el javascript sepa que modal generar
    echo 'error';
    exit;
    }
}
```

Agradecería una respuesta que me explique como es que funciona todo esto de los protocolos por detras, ademas de una solucion porque ahora mismo no se que hacer. Las funciones de mandar la descarga y de mandar el captcha ya han sido probadas por separado, quiero que este archivo unico php `download.php` se comporte de diferentes formas segun las peticiones ajax envie datos.

Comment: voy a añadir que seria bueno en este caso usar WebSockets, si alguien tiene algun problema similar a esto pero escala de forma mas grande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `httpRequest.send(jsonStr);` envías información en pares de datos `variable=valor`, mientras que con `httpRequest.send(1040);` estás enviando solo un dato sin asociarlo a una variable y no hay más datos disponibles en la petición:

```
<?php
$codigo = file_get_contents("php://input");
if($codigo == '1040') {
     // Enviar nueva imagen de captcha
} else {
     // Debes decodificar los datos
     $decoded_data = json_decode($codigo);
}
```

Por cierto, no estás asignando el evento `onload` en la petición para buscar:

```
// Asegura que esta variable es independiente de la otra petición
let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(formData);
httpRequest.open('POST', 'download.php', true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// Asigna el evento onload para ejecutar cuando la petición finalice
httpRequest.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        // Analiza la respuesta
        if(this.response == 'success') {
            // ¿Mostrar mensaje o modal de éxito?
        } else {
            // ¿Mostrar mensaje o modal de error?
        }
    }
};
httpRequest.send(jsonStr);
```

En cuanto a la imagen del captcha en base64, creo que es correcto, porque no necesitas almacenarla en el servidor y evitas posibles problemas de mostrar alguna imagen que se haya guardado previamente en caché.

Te sugiero migrar las peticiones AJAX a la [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) que, aunque al inicio puede parecer más complicado, solo necesitas un poco de paciencia y análisis para ver que es más fácil y te permite recibir las variables directamente en `$_POST`, sin tener que tomar los datos del flujo de entrada y codificarlos.

Comment: me gustaria que me explicaras un poco en tu respuesta acerca de esos codigos extraños que hay que leer con ajax como el 4 o el 200 etc, como mencione un poco de ese trasfondo de los protocolos http

Comment: @EgonStetmann., no entendí lo del 4, pero el `this.status == 200` lo obtienes cuando la petición se realizó correctamente, de otra forma, obtendrías `404` para página o URL no encontrada, `500` para error de servidor, etc. Más info en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status